# basic grep

Tags: grep

I have a large file where each line contains a substring such as ABC123. If I execute

```
grep ABC file.txt
```

or

```
grep ABC1 file.txt
```

I get those lines back as expected, but if I execute

```
grep ABC12 file.txt
```

grep fails to find the corresponding lines.

This seems pretty trivial functionality, but I'm not a heavy user of grep so perhaps I'm missing some gotcha.

Comment: So, let me check my understanding.  There are several lines in the file containing ABC123.  When you run grep with ABC or ABC1, you get those lines back; when you run grep ABC12, you do not get those lines back?  That is pretty improbable - grep will work with long regular expressions, and 5 or 6 characters is not long.  Assume 'pilot error'.   Which platform?  Which version of grep?   (You are right; what you are doing is trivial.  My suspicion would have to be that the file does not contain what you think it does.)

Comment: Please post some example data and command **copied and pasted** from the actual files and commands you use to repro the problem.

Comment: The file did indeed contain a non-printable character between the 2 and 3 characters which didn't otherwise display. In hindsight this should have been the obvious explanation. The od utility proved very helpful here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like

```
od -x -a < filename
```

to dump out the file contents in hex. That'll immediately show you if what you have in your file is what you expect. Which I suspect it isn't :-)

Note: `od` has lots of useful options to help you here. Too many to list, in fact.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a chance your file contains some hidden character, such as 0x00 ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense. Are you sure the file contains "ABC123"?

You can verify this by running following command in a shell

```
echo "ABC123" | grep ABC12
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lines contain ABC123, then "grep ABC12" should get them. Do you perhaps mean that you want to match several different strings, such as ABC1, ABC2 and ABC3? In that case you can try this:

```
grep -E 'ABC1|ABC2|ABC3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is.. `grep` works exactly as it should.. For example, the contents of my test file:

```
$ cat file.txt
ABC
ABC1
ABC12
ABC123
```

..and grep'ing for ABC, ABC1, ABC12, ABC123:

```
$ grep ABC file.txt 
ABC
ABC1
ABC12
ABC123
$ grep ABC1 file.txt 
ABC1
ABC12
ABC123
$ grep ABC12 file.txt 
ABC12
ABC123
$ grep ABC123 file.txt 
ABC123
```

`grep` is basically a filter, any line containing the first argument (ABC, or ABC1 etc) will be displayed. If it doesn't contain the entire string, it will not be displayed